# incompatibility error - element is not allowed to be self closing in current schema

Tags: php, xml, internet-explorer, xhtml

I had a html page that showed no incompatibility issues.  I added some php code at the top for security purposes and now I get these following incompatibility issues due to the page now being a php page

This element is not allowed to be self-closing in the current schema.  The schema is Internet Explorer 8.0.
I tried removing the trailing "/" but it then said the empty element must have an end tag.  I added  and I get the error that it is an empty tag and cannot have a closing tag, it must have a closing slash.  Looks like I came full circle.

This is just one example it occurs with all self closing elements. They are all fine when it is and html page.  The pages still all function as designed and the php code I added is working perfectly.  I am using MS Expression Web 3.0.

here is the php code,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!session_is_registered('Admin')) :
    header('Location: admin_Login.php');
    endif;
    php?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the PHP is being interpreted? Who exactly is giving you the schema error?

Comment: Also, can you post the first few lines of your HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

You are using "`php?>`" as a closing PHP tag, which is wrong : it should be "`?>`"

i.e. you're PHP code should look like this :

```
<?php
// php code here
// more php code here
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ^^^ Yep, we'll see -- with a bit of luck, it will not be any harder than this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Second take:

Try **removing all white space** between after the closing `?>` and the start of your doctype and see whether that helps any.

Comment: yes,100% certain PHP code is being interpreted. White space removed and here are the beginning lines of the code.
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!session_is_registered('Admin')) :
 header('Location: admin_Login.php');
 endif;
 ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- #BeginTemplate "index.dwt" -->

<head>

<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->


The schema error is coming from the compatibility tool in MS Expression Web 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Guys, thanks for the effort.  I just found the problem and it is a user error. I needed to select XHTML 1.0 transitional as the XHTML compatibility standard.  Sorry about that, but I do appreciate your help.